# Cutting a XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following xml:

```
        <Package>
        <PackageHeader>
            <name>External Vendor File</name>
            <description>External vendor file for some purpose</description>
            <version>3.141694baR3</version>
        </PackageHeader>
        <PackageBody>
            <Characteristic id="1">
                <Size>
                    <value>1.68</value>
                    <scale>Meters</scale>
                    <comment>Size can vary, depending on temperature</comment>
                </Size>
                <Weight>
                    <value>9</value>
                    <scale>M*Tons</scale>
                    <comment>His mama is so fat, we had to use another scale</comment>
                </Weight>
                <rating>  
                    <ratingCompany>ISO</ratingCompany>
                    <rating:details xmlns:rating="http://www.w3schools.com/ratingDetails">
                        <rating:value companyDepartment="Finance">A</rating:value>
                        <rating:expirationDate update="1/12/2010">1/1/2014</rating:expirationDate>
                        <rating:comment userID="z94234">You're not Silvia.</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="r24942">You're one of the Kung-Fu Creatures On The Rampage</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="i77880">TWO!</rating:comment>
                        <rating:priority>3</rating:priority>
                    </rating:details>
                </rating>
            </Characteristic>
            <Characteristic id="2">
                <Size/>               
                <Weight/>
                <rating/>
            </Characteristic>
            ...
            <Characteristic id="n"/>
        </PackageBody>
    </Package>
```

And the following Java code:

```
    public class XMLTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            Package currentPackage = new Package();     
            Package sourcePackage = new Package();
            int totalCharacteristics;

            PackageBody currentPackageBody = new PackageBody();     
            Characteristic currentCharacteristic = new Characteristic();        
            rating currentRating = new rating();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sourceFile.xml");

            JAXBContext myCurrentContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Package.class);
            Marshaller m = myCurrentContext.createMarshaller();
            Unmarshaller um = myCurrentContext.createUnmarshaller();

            sourcePackage = (Package)um.unmarshal(fis);

            currentPackage.setPackageHeader(sourcePackage.getPackageHeader());

            totalCharacteristics = sourcePackage.getPackageBody().getCharacteristics().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalCharacteristics; i++)
            {
                currentRating = sourcePackage.getPackageBody().getCharacteristics().get(i).getrating();
            }       

            currentCharacteristic.setrating(currentRating);
            currentPackageBody.getCharacteristics().add(currentCharacteristic);

            currentPackage.setPackageBody(currentPackageBody);      
            m.marshal(currentPackage, new File("targetFile.xml"));
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

Which gives me the next XML:

```
    <Package>
        <PackageHeader>
            <name>External Vendor File</name>
            <description>External vendor file for some purpose</description>
            <version>3.141694baR3</version>
        </PackageHeader>
        <PackageBody>
            <Characteristic id="1">           
                <rating>
                    <ratingCompany>ISO</ratingCompany>
                    <rating:details xmlns:rating="http://www.w3schools.com/ratingDetails">
                        <rating:value companyDepartment="Finance">A</rating:value>
                        <rating:expirationDate update="1/12/2010">1/1/2014</rating:expirationDate>
                        <rating:comment userID="z94234">You're not Silvia.</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="r24942">You're one of the Kung-Fu Creatures On The Rampage</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="i77880">TWO!</rating:comment>
                        <rating:priority>3</rating:priority>
                    </rating:details>
                </rating>
            </Characteristic>
            <Characteristic id="2">           
                <rating/>         
            </Characteristic>
            ...
            <Characteristic id="n"/>
        </PackageBody>
    </Package>
```

And this is what I need:

```
    <Package>
        <PackageHeader>
            <name>External Vendor File</name>
            <description>External vendor file for some purpose</description>
            <version>3.141694baR3</version>
        </PackageHeader>
        <PackageBody>
            <Characteristic>
                <rating id="1">
                    <ratingCompany>ISO</ratingCompany>
                    <rating:details xmlns:rating="http://www.w3schools.com/ratingDetails">                    
                        <rating:comment userID="z94234">You're not Silvia.</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="r24942">You're one of the Kung-Fu Creatures On The Rampage</rating:comment>
                        <rating:comment userID="i77880">TWO!</rating:comment>
                        <rating:priority>3</rating:priority>
                    </rating:details>
                </rating>
            </Characteristic>
            <Characteristic>
                <rating id="2"/>
            </Characteristic>
            ...
            <Characteristic/>
        </PackageBody>
    </Package>
```

But I have a few questions:

- How could I implement a way to read a 4GBs file? (for example, reading it with StAX).
- If I want to filter some tags from source to target(as in the last xml), would I have to assign them one by one to the targetFile? Is there any iterator that might allow me to go through all subnodes and assign them?
- If the sourceFile changes, would I need to rerun the xjc and recompile the whole project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For reading huge XML files, you definitely need a streaming parser like StAX. In addition, you can use a combination of JAXB to selectively map a given piece of xml to java object if you wish work with it. You need to regenerate your JAXB classes only if your schema changes. No need to regenerate if you application code changes.